# Why does pressing shift + tab return false on key.shift?

Tags: node.js

I want to perform an action when the user presses shift + tab, but when I check the value of key.shift it is false. Why is that? Is there a way to capture shift + tab? This is the code I used to discover this:

```
const readline = require('readline');
readline.emitKeypressEvents(process.stdin);
process.stdin.setRawMode(true);
process.stdin.on('keypress', (str, key) => {
  if (key.ctrl && key.name === 'c') {
    process.exit();
  } else {
    console.log(key);
  }
});
console.log('Press any key...');
```

The output from above on shift + tab is:

```
Press any key...
{ sequence: '\t',
  name: 'tab',
  ctrl: false,
  meta: false,
  shift: false }
```

Comment: Seems like platform-specific issue. Here's the output I get on MacOS:

{ sequence: '\u001b[Z', name: 'tab', ctrl: false, meta: false, shift: true, code: '[Z' }

Comment: I noticed that. Is there a way to pick up shift + tab on platforms where node returns false?

Comment: @ChristopherStephenson how did u solve the problem?